# Continuous one to one fuction is monotone

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to solve a problem.Every continuous one to one function is monotone.I tried to prove it by contradiction but could not formalize.Intuitively it looks obvious to me but rigorously I am unable to prove.Please help me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is just about getting you to use definitions, the argument should not be especially tricky. Have you ... written down the relevant definitions, and shaken things around?

Comment: My teacher has told me that every continuous strictly increasing function is one to one and he gave example of tan x which is strictly increasing but not one to one

Comment: $f(x)$ being one to one if and only if $\forall{x_1,x_2}:{x_1}\neq{x_2}\implies{f(x_1)}\neq{f(x_2)}$. This is the case with $f(x)=\tan{x}$, so it sounds to me like your teacher was wrong.

Comment: For $\tan x$, you need to specify the domain: if the domain is $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$, then $\tan$ is strictly increasing and bijective onto $\Bbb R$; if the domain is $\Bbb R\setminus\left\{k\pi+\frac\pi2\,:\,k\in\Bbb Z\right\}$, then $\tan$ is *neither* injective *nor* strictly growing.

Comment: The teacher might have been thinking of $\tan$ with a domain wider than $(-\frac12\pi,\frac12\pi)$. Then $\tan(\pi+x)=\tan(x)$. However, on such domain $\tan$ is not strictly increasing.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose not. Then there must exist some $x \neq y$ for which $f(x) = f(y)$.
Either x > y or x < y. In both cases it contradicts to the fact that the function is strictly increasing $( x > y => f(x) > f(y) )$.