# $f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly increasing function find $f(1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly increasing function such that:

1. $f(x) >  \frac{-1}{x} : \forall  x > 0$
2. $f(x)f(f(x)+1/x)= 1 : \forall x> 0$

find $f(1)$?

I tried different ways but I wasn't able to continue to a solution.I also replace some numbers but they weren't also helpful

Comment: Here is the quick link for MathJax tutorial : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Could you add some context?

Comment: @M. Winter all strictly increasing function are also one to one you can see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858010/is-every-strictly-increasing-function-is-one-to-one

Comment: You stated "you tried different ways". Could you include such attempts to show you put some effort into the solution?

Comment: @f.jalili Not sure what "one to one" means, but if you mean bijective, then this is not true.

Comment: One to one means injective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f(x)\not=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^+$ because of the second condition. Let $f(x)=y$. Then

$$1=f(x)\cdot f\left(f(x)+\frac 1x\right)=y\cdot f\left(y+\frac 1x\right)\quad\Rightarrow\quad f\left(y+\frac 1x\right)=\frac1y.$$

Define $z=y+1/x$. Then we have $f(z)=1/y$ and we can plug this into the same equation again:

$$1=f(z)\cdot f\left(f(z)+\frac 1z\right)=\frac1y\cdot f\left(\frac1y+\frac 1z\right) \quad\Rightarrow\quad  f\left(\frac1y+\frac 1z\right) =y=f(x)$$

But strictly increasing functions must be injective, hence

$$x=\frac1y+\frac1z=\frac1y+\frac 1{y+1/x}=\frac1{f(x)}+\frac 1{f(x)+1/x}$$

multiply by $f(x)$ to find

$$xf(x)=1+\frac1{1+1/(xf(x))}$$

Define $g(x)=xf(x)$:

$$g(x)=1+\frac1{1+1/g(x)}$$

But the equation

$$x=1+\frac1{1+1/x}$$

has exactly the both solutions $x=1/2\cdot(1\pm\sqrt 5)$. Hence $g(x)$ is piece-wise constant. This makes the only solution $f(x)=g(x)/x$ which also fits the other requirements

$$f(x)=\frac 1{2x} \cdot(1-\sqrt 5)\approx -0.618034\cdot \frac 1x.$$

So the value $f(1)=1/2 \cdot(1-\sqrt 5)=-0.618034...$. And I do not see why the condition $f(x)>-1/x$ was necessary as it is satisfied by the only solution anyway.

Comment: the solution was great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is possible:

Assume $f(x) >1 $ Then $\forall y > x: f(y)>1 \Rightarrow f(x)f(y) > 1 $

So we have $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : \ \ \ f(x) \leq 1$

But then $f(x)f(y) = 1 \Rightarrow f(x) = f(y) = 1$ and then the function can not be strictly increasing